# Selecting a model by a timezone attached to it in django

Tags: python, sql, django, orm, django-orm

Imagine I have two models like so:

```
Time(models.Model):
    time = models.TimeField()


Model(models.Model):
    time = models.ForeignKey(Time)
    timezone = models.CharField()
```

Now, I would like to filter these models based on a UTC time.  The raw SQL would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM model
    LEFT JOIN time ON model.time_id = time.id
WHERE time = '01:00:00' AT TIME ZONE model.timezone
```

However, there's a massive and complicated assortment of other filters that can be filtered on which depend on using the django ORM rather than a full raw SQL query.  Is there some convenient way I can use raw SQL for *part* of my query?

Comment: Have you tried this query: Models.objects.filter(time__time = datetime.time(1, 0, 0), timezone = 'UTC')

Comment: The time is not stored in UTC, it's stored in Model.timezone.  So, I need a way to convert my time to Model.timezone at the database level.  This is very easy in SQLAlchemy, so I figured django's orm must offer some obvious support for it that I just wasn't seeing.